# Any workarounds to make RTD code block syntax show in this repo?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am using a repository named [d2l-book](https://book.d2l.ai/) for a project, the library uses Sphinx beneath the hood, but I encounter issues when doing simple Sphinx code syntax such as `linenos`, I guess there should be some workarounds, to reproduce the issue:

```bash
~ $ mkdir -p myblog && cd myblog
~/myblog $ pip install git+https://github.com/d2l-ai/d2l-book
~/myblog $ brew install pandoc # conda install pandoc
~/myblog $ touch index.md && get_started.md
~/myblog $ d2lbook build html
```

In `get_started` please populate the following:

```
.. code-block:: python
    :linenos:

    a = 1
    b = 2
```

I was expecting the line number to appear, but it does not. Any workarounds are appreciated.

Comment: Be very careful with whitespace. Add a blank line after `:linenos:`.

Comment: Yeap, I did, somehow it still throws the error `Error in "code-block" directive: maximum 1 arguments(s) allowed".

Comment: I pushed a sample code in https://github.com/reigHns92/d2l-book-test, the main thing to reproduce is the code blocks in `get_started.md`.

Comment: Not sure how your setup works. get_started.md is a Markdown file presumably, while `code-block` is reStructuredText. Apparently Pandoc is involved somehow.

Comment: Yeap, somehow sad if the line number cannot be added as I really liked the sphinx style of this book. The conversion to rst did not group the `code-block` syntax correctly.

Comment: I have never heard of d2lbook before. It is unclear what this has to do with Read the Docs.

Comment: Can you locate the generated HTML page and take a look at the relevant parts generated? Note that even if sphinx generates the correct HTML elements, it is up to the theme to decide what to render.